# Pagination Wordpress with WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I m using WP query to show my content. It's a custom post type call "enseignement". Query works, but if I want to implement the pagination, that doesn't work. The URL is tranformed in page/2/ but nothing is displayed.

My code

```
            <?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;


                $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'enseignement',
                'posts_per_page' => 2,
                'paged'          => $paged,
                'meta_query' => array(
                         'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'key' => 'cycle', // name of custom field
                            'value' => $_GET['cycle'], // matches exactly "red"
                            'compare' => 'LIKE',
                                                        ),
                array(
                     'key'     => 'lieu',
                     'value'   => $_GET['lieu'],
                     'compare' => 'LIKE',

         ),
    ),


                );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
            <?php if ($loop->have_posts()): while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'enseignement', get_post_format() );?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php
next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $loop->max_num_pages );
             previous_posts_link( 'Next Entries &raquo;' );
             wp_reset_query();
?>
                <?php  endif; ?>
```

Can you help me please ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this function, it works 100%. Adapt yourself and will be ok.

```
<?php

function generatePagination($paged, $loop, $echo = TRUE) {

  $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

  $pages = paginate_links(array(
    'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max(1, $paged),
    'total' => $loop->max_num_pages,
    'type' => 'array',
    'total' => $loop->max_num_pages,
    'prev_next' => TRUE,
    'prev_text' => '<span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>',
    'next_text' => '<span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>'    
  ));

  if (is_array($pages)) {

    $prevText = '<li class="paginated_link disabled"><span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span></li>';
    $nextText = '<li class="paginated_link disabled"><span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span></li>';

    $pagination = '<ul class="pagination">';
    if ($paged == 0 || $paged == 1) {
      $pagination .= $prevText;
    }
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
      $pagination .= '<li class="paginated_link';
      if (strpos($page, 'current') !== false) {
        $pagination .= ' active';
      }
      $pagination .= '">' . $page . '</li>';
    }
    if ($loop->max_num_pages ==  $paged) {
      $pagination .= $nextText;
    }
    $pagination .= '</ul>';

    if ($echo) {
      echo $pagination;
    } else {
      return $pagination;
    }
  }
}

?>
```